# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am new here but I already checked all solutions about my problem here and still didn't fix it.

I want to create simple app with tutorial in Laravel 5.2, and I can't make my controller to work.

I named my app "test" and here is a code:

PagesController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAbout(){
         return view('about');   
    }
}
```

routes.php:

```
Route::get('about', [
    'as' => 'about',
    'uses' => 'PagesController@getAbout'
]);
```

And Controller.php (default):

```
<?php

namespace test\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Do you see any problem here?
I am sure all files are in correct folders.

Comment: did you see that namespace in the controller.php? test\http\....

Comment: yes I see it, but it's just default... nothing changes if I change it to test\app\http\...

Comment: lol you are supposed to replace app with test. Sometimes you need to do a composer dump-autoload command after renaming your app or have new classes.

Comment: and its not test\app, app is a generic name given when you create your first app. Just do what ive posted, and i should fix your errors.

Comment: I changed it to test\http\... but still get the same error.

Answer (score 13):

Error can also occur if **App/Http/Controllers/** folder does not have **Controller.php** file.

Make sure file exists.

Comment: Saved me some time thanks - During package development I copied all my controllers to new package destination (including the default Controller.php file). Once restored all worked OK

Answer (score 3):

To make everything correct, run this.

```
php artisan app:name YourApplicationName
```

it is going to change everything with app to your application name, so you wont need to write manually test everywhere

Comment: It changed all namespaces, but still has the same error

Answer (score 2):

Please correct your namespace in your pagecontroller

```
<?php


namespace test\Http\Controllers;

use test\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAbout(){
         return view('about');   
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

After change in namespace in controller please dump-autoload your composer:

> Composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

My controller now looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace test\Http\Controllers;

use test\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAbout(){
     return view('about');   
    }
}
```

And error is still there

**Update:**

Okay, I created a new project and it finnaly works. I think all ansewrs will be helpful for similiar problems :)

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two namespaces one for the controllers and one for the models in the `controller.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

namespace App\Http\Models;
```

second one was interfering with the first

I removed the second one and voila ... code worked

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time since the original post, but I had the same error, so here's the solution for future reference:

Change:

namespace test\Http\Controllers;

to:

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

and it'll find the Controller class.